# Django filter field on the context processor

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-context

I want to filter a result of a field in django in an html file.
Something like this

```
{{ model.field where id = 2 }}
```

I've been looking for in django docs but i only could find a way to do it on the views.py.
I also so something like javascript when u write a "|" simbol after the request but i still couldnt archieve it

Comment: Send the information from your `views.py`.

Comment: I dont want to , cause i have to set like 10 filters like this one , isnt there a way to do it without the views.py ?

Comment: You can create a custom template tag that returns the filtered set.

Comment: @maks Here ya go https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the {% if %} template tag.  So:

```
{% if model.field == 2 %}
# do something
{% endif %}
```

Here is the official documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#operator

#### Edit:

If `model.field` has a value of 2 then it just needs to be the above.

#### Edit 2:

Without seeing your code, it is hard to tell, but here is how to filter for Users based on Gender in a template:

```
{% for user in users %}
  {% if user.gender == "male" %}
    # do something
    user.username
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Rigth, but want i want to do is return the field that has id 2

Comment: I changed my answer above.  It would just be `model.field == 2`

Comment: It doesnt work :/ , what i want to do is load all the users and count the ones who have some caracteristics , for example sex male or female , i cant do that with your code

Comment: Right and in that "#do something" i want to show the user name